# Why do arrays not need to be cast to pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to learn how pointers work in C and I'm facing a confusing situation.

So basically I have two fields, and a pointer for each.

```
int ages[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int *agesPointer = ages;

// Some printfs I didn't judge useful to keep

int age = 1;
int *agePointer = &age;
```

So `ages` has 3 ints stored in it, which are 1, 2 and 3 and `agesPointer` is pointing to `ages`'s address, right?

Same goes for `age` and `agePointer`, but why do I have to cast `age` to a pointer while I don't for `ages`? I tried adding the cast to `age`s and gets a compiling error, same goes when I remove the cast from `age`, did I miss something? Are arrays a specific case? Thanks to anyone who will help me understanding.

Comment: `Are arrays a specific case?` Yes, together with functions. Arrays "decay" (look that up) to a pointer to their first element.

Comment: Is not a cast, is an assignment. In your first example `ages` (an array) decays into a pointer to the first element (like if `&a[0]` was written) when assigned to `agesPointer`. In the second example you need to use the address-of operator because `age` is not an array.

Comment: Similarly with arguments for `scanf` for example `res = scanf("%d%s", &myInt, myStr);`

Comment: By the C standard, if "ages" is an array of int, then just "ages" in a pointer context means "pointer to the first int at the address of the array", while "&ages" means "pointer to the whole array of ints at the address of the array". Both are the same physical address; the type is only important when you try to do pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

The 2018 C standard says in clause 6.3.2.1, paragraph 3:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type “array of *type*” is converted to an expression with type “pointer to *type*” that points to the initial element of the array object…

Answer (score 0):

An array, when used in an expression, will in most cases *decay* to a pointer to the first element of the array.  So this:

```
int *agesPointer = ages;
```

Is the same as:

```
int *agesPointer = &ages[0];
```

This only works however with arrays.  For variables of other types you need to explicitly take its address.

The reason you can't assign `&ages` to `agesPointer` is because the types are different.  This is one of those cases where the array does *not* decay.  The expression `&ages` has type `int (*)[3]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of `int` of size 3.

Comment: Why are you putting “decay” in bold? It is jargon, not a term being defined. That also means it is sloppy and imprecise. When you are teaching people, it is better to use correct terminology. Per C 2018 6.3.2.1 3, an expression with array type is *converted* to a pointer to its initial element, except when it is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` or is a string literal used to initialize an array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fair enough.  Switched to italics so as not to infer a formal definition.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The Standard is rather sloppy with its terminology, vastly overloading terms like "conversion" and "object" to refer to multiple concepts.  I'm not sure when and by whom the term "decay" was first applied to the implicit conversion of an array-type lvalue into a first-element pointer, but it's been around for a long time and--unlike the term "conversion"--refers to one particular identifiable concept.

Comment: @supercat: The terms are fine here, and, regardless of your feelings about them, the standard is authoritative.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The authority of the Standard is limited to classifying certain things as conforming C implementations, certain things as Strictly Conforming C Programs, certain things as Conforming (but not Strictly Conforming) C Programs, and everything else as none of the above.

Comment: @supercat: The classifications and specifications of the C standard are the standard for questions with the C tag, per the description of the tag. Hence it is authoritative for answers here unless specifically stated otherwise or requested otherwise in the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: While it would make sense to avoid using terms that are defined by the Standard, in ways contrary to such definitions, that doesn't mean that the Standard's failure to recognize a term that is commonly used for something should be interpreted as a prohibition on the use of that term.  If the function of a definition for X is to partition the universe into things that are unambiguously X, things that are unambiguously not X, and things that cannot be unambiguously classified as being X nor as being not X, and if a *good* definition is one that minimizes the latter set, ...

Comment: ...then by that measure the C Standard is severely lacking in good definitions for things.  Do you think I'm being at all unreasonable in what I expect from good definitions?

Answer (score -1):

For starters in this declaration

```
int *agePointer = &age;
```

there is no casting. There is used the unary operator `&` that yields the address of an object to which the operator is applied.

Now here is an answer to your question from the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 2 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the unary &
>   operator, the ++ operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the
>   . operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have
>   array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object
>   (and is no longer an lvalue); **this is called lvalue conversion**.

That is if for example you are using the variable age in the right side of the assignment operator like

```
person_age = age;
```

then the age yields the value stored in the object named `age`. This is called lvalue conversion.

In case of arrays

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type **‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’** that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.

So in this declaration

```
int *agesPointer = ages;
```

`ages` is automatically implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

To get the value as in the case of scalar objects you should dereference the pointer as for example like

```
int person_age = *ages;
```

To get a pointer to the array itself you should write

```
int ages[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int ( *agesPointer )[3] = &ages;
```

That is now the pointer `agesPointer` points to an object of the size `3 * sizeof( int )`.

In this declaration

```
int ages[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int *agesPointer = ages;
```

the pointer `agesPointer` points to an object of the size `sizeof( int )` because the pointer points to the first element of the array.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    {
        int ages[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int *agesPointer = ages;

        printf( "sizeof( *agesPointer ) =  %zu\n", sizeof( *agesPointer ) );
    }

    {
        int ages[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int ( *agesPointer )[3] = &ages;

        printf( "sizeof( *agesPointer ) =  %zu\n", sizeof( *agesPointer ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( *agesPointer ) =  4
sizeof( *agesPointer ) =  12
```